# Printing string range in Python

Tags: python, string

```
s ="XII"

roman = {"I":1, "IV":4, "V":5, "IX":9, "X":10, "XL":40, "L":50, 
                "XC":90, "C":100, "CD":400, "D":500, "CM":900, "M":1000}
out = 0
n = len(s)
i = 0

while i < n:
    
    print (s[i:i+1])
    
    i = i + 1
```

The output of the above code is

```
X
I
I
```

```
s ="XII"

roman = {"I":1, "IV":4, "V":5, "IX":9, "X":10, "XL":40, "L":50, 
                "XC":90, "C":100, "CD":400, "D":500, "CM":900, "M":1000}
out = 0
n = len(s)
i = 0

while i < n:
    
    print (s[i:i+2])
    
    i = i + 1
```

And, the output of the above code

```
XI
II
I
```

I have changed `print (s[i:i+1])` to `print (s[i:i+2])`

Why it does not increment when I am using `(s[i:i+1])` ?  I just wanted to understand the behavior in detail.

Does it assign the same value if we use `+1` ?

Comment: The first output if first char of each of second output. That's uncleat what you don't understand

Comment: `s[i:i+2]` select two characters of `s` each time, and for the last loop, it selects (2:4), which exceeds the length of the string. Therefore, it just prints out the last element. The same goes for the `s[i:i+1]`, but with just one character each time.

Comment: "Why it does not increment...". What is "it"? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The slicing of s is non-inclusive.

```
s[start:end]
```

Meaning the output is up to but not including the end value. This means that the line

```
print (s[i:i+1])
```

is equivalent to

```
print (s[i])
```

According to this reference (https://blog.finxter.com/daily-python-puzzle-overshoot-index-slicing/)

> A little-known feature of slicing is that it has robust end indices. Slicing is robust even if the end index is greater than the maximal sequence index. The slice just takes all elements up to the maximal element. If the start index is out of bounds as well, it returns the empty slice.

The follow code gives

```
s ="123"

roman = {"I":1, "IV":4, "V":5, "IX":9, "X":10, "XL":40, "L":50, 
                "XC":90, "C":100, "CD":400, "D":500, "CM":900, "M":1000}
out = 0
n = len(s)
i = 0

while i < n:
    
    print (s[i:i+2])
    
    
    i = i + 1

print(s[5:7])
```

gives:

```
12
23
3
```